# How do I make this bat file output the results to a .txt file?

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, logfile, logfiles

```
forfiles /p "C:FILEPATH\TO\BE\DELETED\User_1" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -08
forfiles /p "C:FILEPATH\TO\BE\DELETED\User_2" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -08
forfiles /p "C:FILEPATH\TO\BE\DELETED\User_3" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -08
forfiles /p "C:FILEPATH\TO\BE\DELETED\User_4" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -08
forfiles /p "C:FILEPATH\TO\BE\DELETED\User_5" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -08 

@echo off
@echo This purge was successfully completed on the date listed in the file name. 
>purgelog_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_.txt 

( command1
  command2
  ...
  commandN
)
```

Comment: Please, can you expand the description of your problema dn your attempt of solution? Thank you

Comment: How to make this bat file output the results to a .txt file? - by using redirection operators.

Comment: @Jay, I have placed all of your code into a formatted code block, it is however not clear what your original code looked like. Can you please check the code and confirm whether what you see is exactly as you have it in your script.

Answer (score 0):

If this is stored in my.bat, simply use redirection.

```
my.bat >my.txt
```

If you also want stderr to go into the same file, use:

```
my.bat >my.bat 2>&1
```

Note that this will not put the `purgelog*` information go into my.txt because its target file is explicitly specified.